# Mysql log returned values for select queries

Tags: mysql

I want to look at the values returned for some select queries.

I have enabled general logs by adding the following

```
general_log_file=<file-name>
general_log=1
```

The output logs contains the executed query information, but I want to see what was returned for the SELECT queries. Is there any way to achieve this?

Mysql version - 5.7

Comment: MySQL does not store such information - your task is extremely rare, nobody will implement it.

Comment: You have to do it yourself.   If you have created a descendant class for pdo or mysqli, you can log it in there.